# Add missing combination between variables of a data.frame in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

Is there a way to add to a data frame, the potential missing combination of some of its variables (columns)?

As an example, let's take below data.frame.

```
dt <- data.frame(YEAR = c(2010:2015, 2010, 2012:2014), 
           REGION = c(rep("A", 6), rep("B", 4)),
           VALUE = rnorm(10))
# YEAR REGION       VALUE
# 1  2010      A -0.54394115
# 2  2011      A -0.73914582
# 3  2012      A -0.32810183
# 4  2013      A  0.23849083
# 5  2014      A  1.06988425
# 6  2015      A  0.89499079
# 7  2010      B  0.30559946
# 8  2012      B -0.67628277
# 9  2013      B -1.24263277
# 10 2014      B -0.05669371
```

We can denote that `YEAR` 2011 & 2015 are missing for `REGION == B`.

What is the best way of creating those two missing rows, with a specific values as default (such as NA or 0 in this case)?

*Note: One way is to use `expand.grid(dt$YEAR, dt$REGION)` to get all exhaustive combinations among those two variables and then merge via `dplyr::left_join()`, but I think `tidyr::complete()` would be a more efficient solution. However I have difficulties to understand it properly.*

Comment: This should work: `dt %>% complete(YEAR, REGION, fill = list(VALUE = 0))`

Comment: Use `expand.grid` to make a dataframe with all the combinations and then `merge`. I'm pretty sure you can find multiple duplicate questions on SO.

Comment: @IRTFM Yes indeed, see my "note" at the end. But question was more oriented toward "complete" and/or the most efficient way to do that.

Comment: @thesixmax Yes that was that thanks, so easy actually 8)